# How to close another exe from flutter windows application

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I need to close another exe when exiting from the flutter windows app. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: can you explain properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can combine this package [flutter_window_close](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_window_close) with `Process.killPid` method, see the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/Process/killPid.html)

Comment: I have used task kill command with the process name. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the way to do that was run a Process with shutdown related arguments.